# Start Blender with popen in windows 7

Tags: python, windows

I am trying to start and run a blend file with python3 popen under windows 7, but all I am able to do is start Blender.

```
blendFile = "D:\_Blender_Files\atrium.blend"
blenderPath = r"C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\blender-2.71-windows64\blender.exe"
subprocess.Popen([blenderPath, blendFile], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Comment: closing, the issue with slash direction is a common beginner mistake, and not specific to Blender.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because of the escape character "\" and how python handles it. Windows paths on python scripts are a nightmare. So you have to escape the backslash.

Try :

```
blendFile = "D:\\_Blender_Files\\atrium.blend"
blenderPath = r"C:\\Program Files\\Blender Foundation\\blender-2.71-windows64\\blender.exe"
subprocess.Popen([blenderPath, blendFile], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

or with simple slashes (python handles it well) :

```
blendFile = "D:/_Blender_Files/atrium.blend"
```

Comment: Dang, you hit the nail, thank You for the fast reply!